# Как реализовать удаление товара из базы данных, если его нет в наличии(количество=0)?

Tags: python, aiogram, sqlite3

Всем привет, пишу телеграм бота на aiogram, мне нужно, чтобы при определенном количестве(0шт) товара либо удалялся из бд, либо просто не отображался в инлайн кнопках обычным юзерам.
Попытался это сделать при помощи функции, но не получилось:

```
async def delete_item_vpn(state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        products = data['productsvpn']
    if products[5] == 0:
        BotDB.delete_item_vpn(products[0])
    else:
        pass
```

Так у меня выглядит запрос к бд на удаление товара, возможно немного не правильный, если что подскажите:

```
def delete_item_vpn(self, productsid):
    result = self.cursor.execute("DELETE * FROM products_vpn WHERE productsid = ?, amount = ?", (productsid,))
    self.conn.commit()
    return result
```

Comment: products - это что? а в products[5] что содержится?

Comment: products - это запрос к бд, который все забирает

Comment: думаю, вы что-то путаете. Вряд ли у вас запрос к бд - список.  Опять же, что в products[5]

Comment: В одном из хендлеров есть переменная, там запрос к бд, я в эту дату закинул переменную, а в этой функции достал

Comment: То есть в products лежат данные из бд, немного оне правильно выразился,  в products[5] содержится количество товара